# which function of shared pref Editor is best to call?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

a line is given at [Editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html)  is  **All changes you make in an editor are batched, and not copied back to the original SharedPreferences until you call commit() or apply()**

Which is best function to be called if given as commit() and apply() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if its multithreaded and written by multiple threads then `commit()` is the way to since it Synchronized.. or else `apply()` which is asynchronous, so faster and apply never notifies if it fails to write..... see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html#apply%28%29) for more..

Answer (score 4):

`apply()` will update the in-memory-cache of your Shared Preferences immediately and then write the change to the file system in a background thread.

`commit()` will write the change synchronously <del>from the UI-thread</del> from the calling thread, which very well might be the UI-thread. Performing file-system access from the UI thread is generally not a good idea as there is a risk for blocking issues.

Comment: This does not help to decided which is best

Comment: Neither does your question specify what "best" means.

Comment: I think sandy's answer helped me , when to used which function.

Comment: That's OK. As long as you feel you got a satisfying answer to your question, this forum has served it's purpose :)

Answer (score 0):

Commit() returns boolean value telling if it succeeded, apply() doesn't.